# Python turtle problem: couldn't open gif (no such file or directory)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have tried to insert some `.gif` picture on Python form using the `turtle` library. Name of the picture is `nindza.gif`. In order to get picture on window form I use function `bgpic()`.

I just let you know that the picture that I've tried to handle is in the same directory as Python file is. I have to mention that I red all comments about problem noted above. I have read all the instructions but nothing helped me to solve the problem.

Here is the code:

```py
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

# Set the background image to nindza_kornjace.gif
wn.setup(width=600, height=400)
wn.bgpic("nindza.gif")

# exit on click
wn.exitonclick()
```

Every time when I run my code I'm constantly getting following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4072,
in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "nindza_kornjace.gif": no such file or directory
```

I want to note one more thing. When I do relative file path addressing, using the prefix `r` specified in bgpic function before relative file path, I can open the image. Next code work: `wn.bgpic(r"Nedelja6\nindza.gif")`

I'm wondering why the program can run with relative addressing but not when specifying just the file name under quotes (`wn.bgpci("nindza.gif")`).

Comment: You need to use a raw string because of the backslash there (which would otherwise be treated as an escape character). Even `"nindza.gif"` is a relative path, as mentioned in answers in the linked question it is a path relative to the current working directory. The problem simply is that the current working directory is not the same as the directory of the file.

Comment: My .gif file is placed in the same directory as .py file is.

Comment: Please share your folder structure and where you're running the Python script from. Based on `r"Nedelja6\nindza.gif"` working, it sounds like the gif is in a subfolder relative to where you're running the script, or relative to the script itself.

Comment: Folder structure and code are presented in the link below. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z37x79incO6FbRbFLcZjm_IpgmtTcom8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't tried using an absolute path, then try that. Just pointing to the file like "my_pc/user/xxx/folder/nindza.gif"

Comment: Yes, I have. And it's work, but only when I'm using "r" as a prefix in order to denote raw string.  I have to mention that I'm working on Win 11 OS and using the Python 3.11.54 interpreter.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Answers aren't for asking for clarification. You can comment at 50 rep. Thanks.